# Why the last row never gets read?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

Hello well i have one question why the last row never gets read? It dosen´t matter if its only one row in the excel file or 100 rows. The last row never shows up in the List. And i have no clue why....

Here is my Excel File:
[image: Excel File]

and this is my method:

```
public List<string> getListData(bool skipFirstRow, int numberOfColumns, string filepath)
{
    int startpoint = 1;
    int cell = 1;
    int row = 1;

    List<string> stringList = new List<string>();

    //Open Excel (Application)
    var excelApplication = openExcelApplication();
    //Open Excel File
    Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(filepath);
    //Get the Worksheets from the file
    Excel.Sheets excelSheets = excelWorkbook.Worksheets;
    //Select the first Worksheet
    Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelSheets.get_Item(1);

    if (skipFirstRow == true)
    {
        startpoint = 2;
    }

    Excel.Range range = worksheet.get_Range("A" + Convert.ToString(startpoint), Missing.Value);

    while ((range.Cells[startpoint, cell] as Excel.Range).Value2 != null)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns + 1; i++)
        {
            string sValue = (range.Cells[row, cell] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString();
            stringList.Add(sValue);
            cell++;
        }
        startpoint++;
        cell = 1;
        row++;
    }

    closeExcelApplication(excelApplication);

    var result = 
         stringList
        .Select((item, index) => new { Item = item, Index = index })
        .GroupBy(x => x.Index / numberOfColumns)
        .Select(g => string.Join(";", g.Select(x => x.Item)))
        .ToList();

    return result;

}
```

I tried it with the debugger and even google. Then i tried it with the last used row stuff but didnt worked.

```
Excel.Range last = worksheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
Excel.Range range = worksheet.get_Range("A1", last);

int lastUsedRow = last.Row;
int lastUsedColumn = last.Column;
```

Any help or advise would be great so thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your algorithm is buggy.

Let's see what happens when skipFirstRow is true and your Excel sheet has three rows 1, 2 and 3. At the start of the while loop, we have the following situation:

```
startpoint = 2
row = 1
```

During the first iteration, your while loop reads the contents of row 1. After the iteration, we have the following situation:

```
startpoint = 3
row = 2
```

During the second iteration, your while loop reads the contents of row 2. After the iteration, we have the following situation:

```
startpoint = 4
row = 3
```

Since `range.Cells[startpoint, cell]` is empty, your code stops here. Rows 1 and 2 have been read, row 3 has been ignored.

As you can see, the reason for your problem is that you *check* the row in `startpoint` and *read* the row in `row`, and when those two differ, you have a problem. Suggested solution: Drop the `startpoint` variable and use `row` instead.

Answer (score -1):

The excel sheet display first row number as 1
but internally it starts from 0, may be it is reading all the data,put different test data on last column

Comment: Well acording to this so question and msdn http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344442/getting-cell-values-from-excel-api-c-sharp the cell index starts at 1.

Comment: change first row data and last row data and check whether they are read

Comment: well now i tried it with different values but it makes no difference. Without the above changes its still dont reads the last line. But thanks anyway.