# Passing Excel Interop Values to Deedle DataFrame

Tags: c#, excel-interop, deedle

I have a [2D Object Array](http://www.dotnetperls.com/object-array) pulled from an Excel spreadsheet using the [Excel Interop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.application(v=office.14).aspx).

```
data = activeWorksheet.UsedRange.Value2;

data.GetType()
{Name = "Object[,]" FullName = "System.Object[,]"}
```

[Looking at the Deedle documentation on Frames](http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/reference/deedle-frame.html), it appears that I could create a Frame out of a 2D Array `FromArray2D(array)`, or 'a sequence of any .NET objects' `FromRecords(values)`, but it does not seem to be able to take this Object Array.

I have also tried casting to an array, but that only gives me an array of com objects, from which I could reference `Value2`. So that is really no help.

```
cellArray = activeWorksheet.UsedRange.Cells.Cast<Excel.Range>().ToArray<Excel.Range>();

cellArray.GetType()
{Name = "Range[]" FullName = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range[]"}
```

I imagine I could write a function to reconstitute my data, [based on the Github examples](https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/Deedle/blob/master/docs/csharp/Frame.cs#L25), but before I do that....

Is there a type conversion/cast I should be looking at to make an easy Excel -> Deedle DataFrame insertion?

---

**Edit:**

When trying to use `FromArray2D`, I get the below.

```
Frame df = Frame.FromArray2D(data);

'Frame.FromArray2D(data)' threw an exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException'
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HResult: -2146233080
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: null
    Message: "Index was outside the bounds of the array."
    Source: "Deedle"
    StackTrace: "   at Deedle.Frame.FromArray2D[T](T[,] array) in C:\\code\\deedle\\src\\Deedle\\FrameExtensions.fs:line 281\r\n   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)"
    TargetSite: {Deedle.Frame`2[System.Int32,System.Int32] FromArray2D[T](T[,])}
```

This may be because the Excel Interop uses 1-index arrays, not 0-index, so there is a mismatch?

I can't find that Excel quirk in the official documentation, but SO is littered with answers saying as much. Case in point: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14345372/1886901

Comment: What error do you get when you try using `FromArray2D`?

Comment: Updated my question to include the error for `FromArray2D`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best method or not, but shifting the array to a 0-index lets `FromArray2D` pass with no error.

```
data = activeWorksheet.UsedRange.Value2;    
string[,] newData = new string[data.GetLength(0), data.GetLength(1)];
for (int x = 0; x < data.GetLength(0); x++)
{
  for (int y = 0; y < data.GetLength(1); y++)
  {
    newData[x, y] = data[x + 1, y + 1].ToString();
  }
}
var df = Frame.FromArray2D(newData);
```